# How to get left substring in mysql

Tags: mysql, substring, string-matching

it sems odd, but I can't find a quick and simple way to solve my task:

I have many rows with different absolute paths like:

- /application/themes/openbank/images/prettyPhoto/light_square/default_thumbnail.gif
- /application/themes/openbank/images/default_thumbnail.png
- /application/themes/openbank/images/prettyPhoto/light_square/a_s.pdf

and I want to split them in

- parent_path ("e.g. /application/themes/openbank/images/prettyPhoto/light_square/")
- file_name ("e.g. default_thumbnail.gif")

NB: file name's lenght and number of separators is variable.

With

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('/application/themes/openbank/images/prettyPhoto/light_square/default_thumbnail.gif', '/', -1)
```

I correctly get the file_name, 
but I can't find a way to retrieve the left part.
I tried LEFT(), RIGHT(), and [all other mysql's string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) with no success

Linuxatico

Comment: All are good and complete answers (VMai, Brian Ridgeway and Ronak Shah's) and all deserve an "accepted answer mark". I think that the most complete and clean is that one of @VMai, in addiction, the fiddle is very auto explicative. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be the combination of LEFT, SUBSTRING_INDEX and CHAR_LENGTH:
My solution takes the left part of the string with length = length(absolute path) - length(file part).

```
SET @content = '/application/themes/openbank/images/prettyPhoto/light_square/default_thumbnail.gif';
SELECT 
    LEFT(
       @content, 
       CHAR_LENGTH(@content) - CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@content, '/', -1))
    );
```

See the three first answers working in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51cb5/2).

I'm sure there are some other ways too to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Try below to get parent_path

```
select reverse(substring(reverse('/application/themes/openbank/images/prettyPhoto/light_square/default_thumbnail.gif'),instr(reverse('/application/themes/openbank/images/prettyPhoto/light_square/default_thumbnail.gif'),'/')))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select substr( path, 1, instr(path, substring_index( path, '/', -1)) - 1 ) as "PARENT_PATH", substring_index(path, '/', -1 ) as "FILE_NAME" from table1;
```

Comment: +1 too, included your solution in my fiddle. I hope you don't mind.